# Adding image to GridView created in CodeBehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

First thing I do is create a Datatable and then bind it to a GridView
Here is my code

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 DataColumn imgC = dt.Columns.Add("img", typeof(string));
 DataRow  row1 = dt.NewRow();
 row1["img"] = "~images/foo.png";

 GridView gv = new GridView();
 gv.DataSource = dt;
 gv.DataBind();
 cust_services.Controls.Add(gv);
```

I'm not sure where to go from here, as it just displays text, I have tried creating an Image and just writing

```
row1["img"] = img;
```

Comment: try this example / tutorial - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479350.aspx pay attention to this line in the example `dr["PictureURL"] = ResolveUrl("~/DisplayingImages/Images/Winter.jpg");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `<asp:ImageField/>` within the the `Gridview` to achieve this. So your markup will look like

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="Value" ControlStyle-Width="100" ControlStyle-Height="100" HeaderText="My Image" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In your C# code you can use `List` to add the images. So something as simple as

```
List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
files.Add(new ListItem("~/Images/SomeImage.jpg"));

GridView2.DataSource = files;
GridView2.DataBind();
```

This will only add one image to the grid. If you want to add all the images to the grid that are in a particular directory then just use a `foreach` loop.

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"));
    List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
    foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        files.Add(new ListItem(fileName, "~/Images/" + fileName));
    }
    GridView2.DataSource = files;
    GridView2.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your binding is correct but you need to bind the image to an ImageField in your GridView as well.

```
<asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="BoundName"></asp:ImageField>
```